# MQL4 EA | Why are my string variables not included in my email body?

Tags: mql4

Right, I have an email send ontaining information as to the initialisation status of my EA.

Why are my string variables not being included in my email body, despite declaring all string variables?

```js
int      hourOfDay = Hour();
int      startingHour = 12;
bool     BarTime;
string   eaName = WindowExpertName();
bool     InitOrders;
bool     InitTime;
string   symbol = OrderSymbol();

int OnInit()
{
   /*lastStamp = 0;
   GetMarketInfo_PerSymbol(Symbol(), true);
   fEvents(MODE_INIT);*/ /*Unrelated Code*/
   
   InitOrders = OrdersTotal();
   
   if(InitOrders == 0){
   
      InitOrders = true;
      Print("EA has been initialised to true");
   
   }else{
   
      InitOrders = false;
      Print("EA has been initialised to false");
   
   }
         
   InitTime = (hourOfDay >= startingHour && hourOfDay < 20);
   
   if(InitTime = true){
      Print("Trades will be placed");
      SendMail("Initialisation confirmation: "+(eaName),"Initialised by: User\n\nEA Name: "+(eaName)+"\n\nAsset: Forex CFD "+(symbol)+"\n\nDate of Initialisation "+TimeToString(TimeCurrent(),TIME_DATE | TIME_MINUTES)+" (This may differ from GMT)\n\nInitTime Status: Trades will be placed\n\nInitOrders: "+(InitOrders == True? "You have no open positions" : "You have an open position"));   
   
   }else{
   
      InitTime = false;
      Print("Trades will not be placed.");
      MessageBox("Trades will not be placed until "+IntegerToString(startingHour - 2,0)+"AM GMT\n\nIf you feel this is incorrect, please email us at xxx","| Important Notification",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_TOPMOST);
      SendMail("Initialisation confirmation: "+(eaName),"Initialised by: User\n\nEA Name: "+(eaName)+"\n\nAsset: Forex CFD "+(symbol)+"\n\nDate of Initialisation "+TimeToString(TimeCurrent(),TIME_DATE | TIME_MINUTES)+" (This may differ from GMT)\n\nInitTime Status: Trades will not be placed\n\nInitOrders: "+(InitOrders == True? "You have no open positions" : "You have an open position"));
   }
   
BarTime=Time[0];
   
return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);

}
```

[image: email test result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not allocate variables in the header, it should properly be carried out in the init block (this is where you initialise and can properly allocate variables). You are also using OrderSymbol() without selecting an order so this will always be empty.

```
int      hourOfDay;
int      startingHour;
bool     BarTime;
string   eaName;
bool     InitOrders;
bool     InitTime;
string   symbol;

int OnInit()
{
   hourOfDay = Hour();
   startingHour = 12;
   eaName = WindowExpertName();
   symbol = Symbol();

   /*lastStamp = 0;
   GetMarketInfo_PerSymbol(Symbol(), true);
   fEvents(MODE_INIT);*/ /*Unrelated Code*/
   
   InitOrders = OrdersTotal();
   
   if(InitOrders == 0){
 
      InitOrders = true;
      Print("EA has been initialised to true");
 
   }else{

      InitOrders = false;
      Print("EA has been initialised to false");

   }
     
   InitTime = (hourOfDay >= startingHour && hourOfDay < 20);

   if(InitTime = true){
      Print("Trades will be placed");
      SendMail("Initialisation confirmation: "+(eaName),"Initialised by: User\n\nEA Name: "+(eaName)+"\n\nAsset: Forex CFD "+(symbol)+"\n\nDate of Initialisation "+TimeToString(TimeCurrent(),TIME_DATE | TIME_MINUTES)+" (This may differ from GMT)\n\nInitTime Status: Trades will be placed\n\nInitOrders: "+(InitOrders == True? "You have no open positions" : "You have an open position"));   

   }else{

      InitTime = false;
      Print("Trades will not be placed.");
      MessageBox("Trades will not be placed until "+IntegerToString(startingHour - 2,0)+"AM GMT\n\nIf you feel this is incorrect, please email us at xxx","| Important Notification",MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_TOPMOST);
      SendMail("Initialisation confirmation: "+(eaName),"Initialised by: User\n\nEA Name:"+(eaName)+"\n\nAsset: Forex CFD "+(symbol)+"\n\nDate of Initialisation "+TimeToString(TimeCurrent(),TIME_DATE | TIME_MINUTES)+" (This may differ from GMT)\n\nInitTime Status: Trades will not be placed\n\nInitOrders: "+(InitOrders == True? "You have no open positions" : "You have an open position"));
   }

BarTime=Time[0];

return(INIT_SUCCEEDED);

}
```

Comment: Strewth! It worked. Fair play to you, I will mark your answer as correct. All the best,